# In Joomla2.5, how to differentiate the user login from the front-end or backend

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

How to find out the user login from the site frontend or from the admin backend.

Is there any way to find out the user login?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this, I think it may help you.

```
<?php

$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$user = JFactory::getUser();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('s.time, s.client_id, u.id, u.name, u.username');
$query->from('#__session AS s');
$query->leftJoin('#__users AS u ON s.userid = u.id');
$query->where('s.guest = 0');
$db->setQuery($query);
$users = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach ($users as $user)
{
    if($user->client_id) {
        echo JText::_('JADMINISTRATOR');
    } else {
        echo JText::_('JSITE');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i tried with this code, its shows all of the users who logged-in at the time.

Comment: @Anwar if this answer has solved your problem you can check it as accepted